# Where are the calls made to a smart contract?

Tags: web3js, metamask

I know it might sound as a dumb question, but I deployed my first smart contract and made a call to one of its methods. I opened the dev tools to see how I am sending the "request" but nothing shows up in the network tab (I have selected "All"). I think I heard RPC is used but I would still expect to see some RPC calls in the network tab. I am using web3.js to call methods from my smart contract.

Comment: Where did you deployed the contract?

Comment: To the Rinkeby Test Network.

Comment: @davidaap Are you using metamask? In that case the calls are made by a plugin. I don't know if they will show up in the page dev tools.

Comment: @Ismael yes, I am using Metamask. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you want the calls to show up in the networks tab, you're going to have to use a web3 API like Infura or Alchemy. You could look up how to connect to a web3 instance via any of those and use it to make calls.